# x86 ASM Linux - Using the .bss Section

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I hope these questions is rather simple: (NASM Compiler, Linux, x86 Intel Syntax)

PART 1:

I am trying to figure out how to use the .bss section of an Assembly program to find a way to store values, like a value from an operation (+ - * /), to an declared variable. For example:

```
section .bss

variable:  resb 50                                       ;Imaginary buffer

section .text

add 10,1                                                 ;Operation
;move the result into variable
```

So, I know it is possible to do this with the kernel intterupt for reading user input (but that involves strings, but is there a way to copy this value into the *variable* variable so that it can be used later? This would be much easier than having to push and pop two things on and off the stack.

PART 2:

Is there a way to remove the value of the variable in the .bss section? In other words, if I want to store a new value in the .bss variable, how could I do it without the characters/values already in the variable not getting compounded with the new value(s)?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
section .bss

variable: resb 4
```

... the symbol `variable` now refers to the address of 4 bytes of storage in the `.bss` section (i.e. enough to store a 32-bit value in).

```
section .text
...
mov eax, 123
mov [variable], eax
```

... sets the `eax` register to `123`, and then stores the value of `eax` in the location addressed by the symbol `variable`.

```
mov eax, [variable]
```

... reads the value currently stored in the location addressed by `variable` into the `eax` register.

```
mov eax, 456
mov [variable], eax
```

... stores a new value, overwriting the previous one.

Comment: Very well explained, as always!

Comment: `mov dword [variable], 123` is also worth mentioning.  Often you can just use registers instead of any static storage at all, but if you do need to store a constant to memory you can do it directly instead of bouncing through a register.