# How to specify .bss section on a elf target?

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I want to define a bss section for  my elf. But when i google for it only below flags would be supported for ELF targets using .section directive.

```
a section is allocatable 
e section is excluded from executable and shared library. 
w section is writable 
x section is executable 
M section is mergeable 
S section contains zero terminated strings 
G section is a member of a section group 
T section is used for thread-local-storage 
? section is a member of the previously-current section's group, if any
```

Can anyone help me to specify bss section or else any alternative option.

Comment: The compiler and linker will automatically add a .bss section. Could you clarify what you actually want to do? (So where do you want to specify it, in a linker script, from the commandline, using which tool).

Comment: not in linker script, i have it in .S file.

Comment: does this answer your question? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145243/x86-asm-linux-using-the-bss-section>

Comment: @sebastian no. I have like .section "sectionname", "ab" So i am getting a compilation error "Fatal error: unrecognized .section attribute: want a,e,w,x,M,S,G,T" because "b" isn't supported for elf. BTW i am using gcc compiler.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: @SebastianRiese Please check my previous comment.

Comment: Why do you need a named .bss section? Why don't you allocate space in the .bss section?

Comment: No, i can't do that.

Comment: You could also allocate memory in a named section and zero the section by hand.